# Implement a hash table

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm trying to create an efficient look-up table in **C**.

I have an integer as a key and a variable length `char*` as the value.

I've looked at `uthash`, but this requires a fixed length `char*` value. If I make this a big number, then I'm using too much memory.

```
struct my_struct {
    int key;
    char value[10];             
    UT_hash_handle hh;
};
```

Has anyone got any pointers? Any insight greatly appreciated.

---

Thanks everyone for the answers. I've gone with `uthash` and defined my own custom struct to accommodate my data.

Comment: At a low level, I'd suggest using an array of linked-lists to back your hash table.  Your hash function just needs to map `key` to a valid value in the array, and then you just append your value to the linked-list that exists there.  Like any other hash implementation, this will perform efficiently so long as your hash function distributes keys relatively evenly within the array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. But how do I efficiently find the correct key?

Comment: @Eamorr, finding the key is responsibility of the hash function. The hash needs to be deterministic: always delivering the same result for the same input. Then whatever key was used to store the value will retrieve the same value later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the `value` field as `void *value`.

This way you can have any type of data as the value, but the responsibility for allocating and freeing it will be delegated to the client code.

Answer (score 15):

You first have to think of your collision strategy:

1. Will you have multiple hash functions?
2. Or will you have to use containers inside of the hashtable?

We'll pick 1.

Then you have to choose a nicely distributed hash function. For the example, we'll pick

```
int hash_fun(int key, int try, int max) {
    return (key + try) % max;
}
```

If you need something better, maybe have a look at the [middle-squared method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method).

Then, you'll have to decide, what a hash table is.

```
struct hash_table {
    int max;
    int number_of_elements;
    struct my_struct **elements;
};
```

Then, we'll have to define how to insert and to retrieve.

```
int hash_insert(struct my_struct *data, struct hash_table *hash_table) {
    int try, hash;
    if(hash_table->number_of_elements >= hash_table->max) {
        return 0; // FULL
    }
    for(try = 0; true; try++) {
        hash = hash_fun(data->key, try, hash_table->max);
        if(hash_table->elements[hash] == 0) { // empty cell
            hash_table->elements[hash] = data;
            hash_table->number_of_elements++;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

struct my_struct *hash_retrieve(int key, struct hash_table *hash_table) {
    int try, hash;
    for(try = 0; true; try++) {
        hash = hash_fun(key, try, hash_table->max);
        if(hash_table->elements[hash] == 0) {
            return 0; // Nothing found
        }
        if(hash_table->elements[hash]->key == key) {
            return hash_table->elements[hash];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And least a method to remove:

```
int hash_delete(int key, struct hash_table *hash_table) {
    int try, hash;
    for(try = 0; true; try++) {
        hash = hash_fun(key, try, hash_table->max);
        if(hash_table->elements[hash] == 0) {
            return 0; // Nothing found
        }
        if(hash_table->elements[hash]->key == key) {
            hash_table->number_of_elements--;
            hash_table->elements[hash] = 0;
            return 1; // Success
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In `hash_insert` function, should `hash_table->number_of_elements < hash_table->max` be `hash_table->number_of_elements >= hash_table->max` instead?

Comment: Correct. With open addressing, the hash function needs to involve the capacity obviously, and rehashing needs to occur with the new capacity. This is a minimally simple implementation and I can only encourage anyone to read up on more sophisticated techniques.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on the distribution of your key field. For example, if it's a unique value always between 0 and 255 inclusive, just use `key % 256` to select the bucket and you have a perfect hash.

If it's equally distributed across all possible `int` values, any function which gives you an equally distributed hash value will do (such as the afore-mentioned `key % 256`) albeit with multiple values in each bucket.

Without knowing the distribution, it's a little hard to talk about efficient hashes.