# How do I Print a Hash Table in C?

Tags: c, hashtable, stdout

I have a program in C that creates a hash table. I want to know what it is, but I am unsure how to print it out or display it.  I have pasted the program below. I am rather new to hash tables so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TABLE_SIZE  7
#define NUM_INPUTS  7

int hash( char *s )
        /* Note, this is a horrible hash function.  It's here for
                instructional purposes */
{
        return strlen( s ) % TABLE_SIZE ;
}

typedef struct entry
{
        char *key;
        int     val;
        struct entry *next;
} entry;

entry* table[ TABLE_SIZE ] = { NULL };

void insert( char *s, int v )
        /* this insert is NOT checking for duplicates.  :/ */
{
        int h = hash( s );
        entry *t = (entry*) malloc( sizeof( entry ));

        t->key = s;
        t->val = v;
        t->next = table[h];
        table[h] = t;
}

void clean_table()
{
        entry *p, *q;
        int i;

        for( i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; ++i )
        {
                for( p=table[i]; p!=NULL; p=q )
                {
                        q = p->next;
                        free( p );
                }
        }       // for each entry
}       // clean_table

int main()
{
        char* keyList[] = { "Jaga", "Jesse", "Cos", "Kate", "Nash", "Vera",
                "Bob" };

        int valList[] = { 24, 78, 86, 28, 11, 99, 38 };

        int i;

        for( i=0; i<NUM_INPUTS; ++i )
                insert( keyList[i], valList[i] );

        /* what does the table look like here? */

        clean_table();

        return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: 1. Loop through your `table` array in the range, [0, TABLE_SIZE) and 2. for each entry: traverse the singly-linked list and 3. `printf`. If that is difficult for you to understand, let us know in which part.

Comment: What would it look like to traverse the singly linked list?

Comment: `for (struct entry* node = table[0]; node; node = node->next) {/* do stuff with node */}

Comment: You start off creating a pointer to the head of the list. While it's not null, you process it. And then to get to the next one, you set the pointer to point to the next node.

Comment: Ok.  I also want to write a function that will take a key and a reference to an integer and fill the reference with the appropriate value and return true if found and return 0 if not.  would there be an easy way to implement that?

Comment: Interesting that you use the word, `reference`. Do you come from a background in a different language, like Java or C++? In C the pointer is your reference. `int search(const char* key, int* out_val);`

Comment: Write to `*out_val` if the key is found and return non-zero for success.

Comment: In that case, your pointer is pretty much a one-to-one substitution with a reference in this context (only with some slight differences in rules and some extended abilities to jump around in memory and point at different things later on). So in C++, `bool search(const string& key, int& out_val)` becomes like this: `int search(const char* key, int* out_val)`. And because it's a pointer, you pass like `int x; search(..., &x);` And to write to that, you write to `*out_val` (the pointee).

Comment: Put crudely, pointers are not too different from your C++ references except you'll write a little more code like `&x` and `*x` because of the explicit need to indicate addresses and explicitly dereference to get to the pointee.

Comment: I'll show you in answer form since it's a little easier there.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). This helps to understand how the program work.

Comment: Please do not destroy your question after you've gotten an answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments, a search function as desired would look like this:

```
int search(const char* key, int* out_val)
{
    // Find the hash index into the table.
    const int index = hash(key);

    // Now do a linear search through the linked list.
    for (struct entry* node = table[index]; node; node = node->next)
    {
         // If we find a node with a matching key:
         if (strcmp(node->key, key) == 0)
         {
              // Output the value and return 1 for success.
              *out_val = node->val;
              return 1;
         }
    }
    // We didn't find anything. Return 0 for failure.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a simple Hash Table in C. It doesn't really do any error handling, so this is not at all suitable for production, but it should help to see an [example of a working implementation](https://gist.github.com/tonious/1377667). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844739/c-implement-a-hash-table) is another post helping someone work through a hash table implementation in C.