# Simple program: checking if one array is included in another or viceversa

Tags: c

I want to make a simple function that works as described in the comments below:

```
int included(const int v1[], const int v2[], int dim1, int dim2)
{
    int i, j;
    int found;
    int amount;

    for(i = amount = 0; i < dim1; i++)
    {
        found = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < dim2 && !found; j++)
        {
            if(v1[i] == v2[j])
            {
                amount++;
                found = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(amount >= dim2)          /*  Returns 0 if v1's elements are      */
        return 2;               /*  not in v2, and v2's are not in v1,  */
    if(amount >= dim1)          /*  Returns 1 if v1's elements are in v2*/
        return 1;               /*  And returns 2 if v2's elements are  */
    return 0;                   /*  in v1. If both situations happen    */
}                               /*  it returns whatever (1 or 2).       */
```

Order of the elements does not matter, for example `v1[5]={0,1,1,1,1}, v2[2]={1,0}` should return either 1 or 2. But the code does not work as is right now.

Is there any simple way to make this as efficient as possible? (I'm a beginner in c).

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: In my example, I'd call it by `included(v1,v2,5,2);`.

Comment: Do you really mean, *Returns 0 if **at least one of** `v1`'s elements is not in `v2`, and **at least one of** `v2`'s elements is not in `v1`*?

Comment: Is there a limit on the values of `v1` and `v2`, or do you need to handle anything that fits in an `int`?

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant @lurker. Thanks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I need to handle anything that fits in ant int.

Comment: You could change `for(j = 0; j < dim2 && !found; j++)` to `for(j = 0; j < dim2 && amount < INT_MAX; j++)` and add `if (amount == INT_MAX && j <= dim2)` (*print an error, INT_MAX reached before end of loop*) immediately following the loop. That will allow a full `amount` count while also preventing overflow. (if that is wanted -- otherwise, if just checking for any included element, the original is fine)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm's logic is not right: you cannot determine the answer from a simple count.

> Is there any simple way to make this as efficient as possible?

Let's start by making it right, and then discuss optimization.

One way to implement the logic is to introduce a function that would tell you if any elements of `int a[]` are missing from `int b[]`:

```
int missing(const int a[], const int b[], size_t dimA, size_t dimB) {
    // Return 1 if there exists an element of a[]
    // that is not present in b[]. Otherwise return 0.
    ...
}
```

Now your `included()` function can be implemented as follows:

```
int included(const int v1[], const int v2[], int dim1, int dim2) {
    int missing1in2 = missing(v1, v2, dim1, dim2);
    int missing2in1 = missing(v2, v1, dim2, dim1);
    if (missing1in2 && missing2in1) {
        // Both sets have elements outside of each other
        return 0;
    }
    return missing2in1 ? 1 : 2;
}
```

If you implement `missing` in the simple way that your code uses (two nested loops and a flag; break early if the item is found; return `0` if `found` is not set upon completion of the *inner* loop) the code complexity will be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

You can make it go faster by sorting both arrays, which lets you determine if there are missing elements in O(n). If you use `qsort` algorithm, the overall code complexity would be O(n log<sub>2</sub>n).

You can simplify this even further by employing a [*hash table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). However, C standard library lacks out-of-the-box implementation, so you would need to come up with your own or [borrow someone else's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6845093/335858). This would bring the complexity down to O(n).

Comment: The arrays may have repeated elements, how does it fail in that case, @chqrlie?

Comment: You are correct.  The specification is incomplete but does cover duplicate elements.